# jquery and js in 'help text' code editor of a page item in oracle apex 5.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oracle-apex-5.1

I know javascript and jquery can be used in the 'help text' area of a page item. But how can I refer to page variables inside js here.
I tried this code:

```
<html>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/i/libraries/jquery/2.2.3/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if($v("P2_ENAME") == 'Arjun') {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Good day!";
    }
    </script>
   <p id="demo">
       Hai !!!
    </p> 

</html>
```

With the above code, I am not getting any console errors. But even if the the value of P2_ENAME = 'Arjun', the text displayed is 'Hai!!!'.

I am using oracle apex 5.1

Comment: What is this variable and where are you getting it from $v("P2_ENAME") ? Please expand your code to show more as it is currently hard to reproduce the problem and help you out.

Comment: I got the error in that code. Instead of $v("P2_ENAME") ,if I reference it like this:' $("#P2_NEW").val() ', then the value is getting picked up in a 'normal' page in oracle apex. But mine is modal dialog, and there '#P2_ENAME'.val()   value acomes as undefined.So I am stuck again..

Comment: By the way, P2_ENAME is just the name of  a drop down field in the page.@Igor